# Regex remove the specials chars and keep the accents and ()@-_'& chars

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

In my current PHP code I have many problems with the specials chars and I wan to replace them with a regex. Do you know how I can make that's ?

I want to accept just the :

All letters with accents
All numbers
()@-_'&

My regex:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\-]/u', '', $string);
```

That's all. This regex it's to make a clean header to download file.

Thanks you all for your helping.
Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just include allowed characters in your character class:

```
$replaced = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}0-9()@_'&-]+/u", '', $string);
```

ALso better to use a quantifier `+` here to make replacement process more efficient since multiple characters will be matched and replaced in each call.

Comment: Nice thanks you ! 
Your regular expression is the same of `preg_replace("/[^\p{L}0-9\(\)\@\_\'\&\-]+/u", '', $string);`?

Comment: Yes but you don't need to do all that excessive escaping inside the character class.

Comment: Hooo okay ! Thanks you for your help. :) I click to resolved !

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `\pL` for letters, you could use `\pN` for numbers:

```
preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}()@_'&-]+/u", '', $string);
```